# Javascript .toggle only works 1.5 times

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I'm trying to make an image popup using the .toggle function in javascript however it only works 1.5 times.

I can click it and it opens it, click the background to close it, open it again but then i cannot close it.

Here is the codepen with everything needed, any guidance would be great so thanks in advance. (im pretty new to js
https://codepen.io/user843/pen/gOXobZZ

```
function prodImgPopup(a) {
popUpModal = document.querySelector(".prodimgpop")
popupImgID = document.getElementById("popID")
popUpModal.classList.toggle("product-popup-show")
popupImgID.src = a.src
popUpModal.addEventListener("click", e => {
    popUpModal.classList.toggle("product-popup-show")
})
```

Comment: every time you click the image you add the event listener ... therefore, when you've clicked the image twice, it has the event listener running twice ... which means it does toggle toggle ... can you see the issue?

Answer (score 1):

every time you click the image you add the event listener ... therefore, when you've clicked the image twice, it has the event listener running twice ... which means it does toggle twice

Of course toggling twice === do nothing

Change your code to

```
const popUpModal = document.querySelector(".prodimgpop")
const popupImgID = document.getElementById("popID")
popUpModal.addEventListener("click", e => {
  popUpModal.classList.remove("product-popup-show")
});
function prodImgPopup(a) {
    popupImgID.src = a.src
    popUpModal.classList.add("product-popup-show")
}
```

edit: not sure why every second time you load that page you get that `prodImgPopup` is undefined

anyway - here's an alternative

```
const popUpModal = document.querySelector(".prodimgpop");
const popupImgID = document.getElementById("popID");
popUpModal.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  popUpModal.classList.remove("product-popup-show");
});
document.querySelectorAll("img[loading=lazy]").forEach((img) =>
  img.addEventListener("click", (prodImgPopup) => {
    popupImgID.src = img.src;
    popUpModal.classList.add("product-popup-show");
  })
);
```

and remove the `onclick=` from those `<img loading="lazy" ...>` images

You also need CSS change to fix the latent image

```
.prodimgpop {
  display: none;
}
.prodimgpop.product-popup-show {
  display: block;
}
```

Here's the code all fixed up and running

```js
const popUpModal = document.querySelector(".prodimgpop");
const popupImgID = document.getElementById("popID");
popUpModal.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  popUpModal.classList.remove("product-popup-show");
});
function prodImgPopup(a) {
  popupImgID.src = this.src;
  popUpModal.classList.add("product-popup-show");
}
document.querySelectorAll("img[loading=lazy]").forEach((img) =>
  img.addEventListener("click", (prodImgPopup) => {
    popupImgID.src = img.src;
    popUpModal.classList.add("product-popup-show");
  })
);
```

```css
.product-popup {
    display: none;
}
.product-popup-show {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100000;
    background-color: rgba(32,32,32, .8);
    position: fixed;
}
.popup-img {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5rem;
}
.popup-img .img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 750px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
/* fix popup display */
.prodimgpop {
  display: none;
}
.prodimgpop.product-popup-show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="prod">
  <img loading="lazy" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602471615287-d733c59b79c4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1171&q=80" class="img prod-img" alt="">
  <img loading="lazy" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533689476487-034f57831a58?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1171&q=80" class="img prod-img" alt="">
</div>

<div id="productPop" class="prodimgpop">
  <div class="popup-img">
    <img id="popID" class="img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this gives me this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'popupImgID' before initialization
    at prodImgPopup"

Comment: yeah, I know, it does that like every second time ... weird

Comment: @Caleby - I wonder if it's because of the missing `</div>` ... not sure why that would make the code break 50% of the time, but ... codepen will be codepen

Comment: That code works, however, while it hides the popup it leaves an image below the others with whatever the last clicked image was

Comment: huh? it shouldn't be any different to what your code attempted to do - hint: your original code does the same thing

Comment: @Caleby - the issue is with **your** styling - edited and added fix for you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jaromanda, the event listener is being added each time you click. Try changing the Javascript to this.

```
function prodImgPopup(a) {
    popUpModal = document.querySelector(".prodimgpop")
    popupImgID = document.getElementById("popID")
    popUpModal.classList.toggle("product-popup-show")
    popupImgID.src = a.src
}

const popupdisplay = document.querySelector("#productPop");
popupdisplay.addEventListener("click", e => {
        popUpModal.classList.toggle("product-popup-show")
    });
```